# Excel VBA - Should I use a multidimensional array or Select Case Structure to optimize performance?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, multidimensional-array

I have about 450,000 cells with data in a column. I have been using the Select Case structure for one column to determine the output of another. But I noticed it is possibly iterating over every cell causing a longer processing time. Should I use a multidimensional array instead?

Here is an example:

```
Dim rng As Range, cl As Range

Set rng = Range("A1:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

For Each cl In rng

Dim outCell2 As Range
Set outCell2 = cl.Offset(0, 55)

Select Case Trim(cl.Text)

    Case "671518779618"

        outcell1` = "beyueuynemui"

    Case "671518779618"

        outcell1` = "beyueuynemui"

    Case "671518779618"

        outcell1` = "beyueuynemui"

End Select
```

Comment: I'm assuming there's supposed to be a Next statement at the end of all that and that outcell1` is suppose to read outcell2. That notwithstanding, of course it's iterating over every cell in your defined range, that's exactly what a `For Each` loop is for. Which brings me to my point, what exactly is wrong with your code besides it being slow and why do you think a multidimensional array is the solution? If this is actual working code your question might be better asked at [CodeReview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Did you actually want to look at every cell?

Answer (score -1):

```
Dim ar as Variant
Dim i as Long

ar = rng
For i = 1 to UBound(ar,1)
    Select Case Trim(ar(i, 1))
        Case ...
            MyWorksheet.Cells(i, 55) = "beyueuynemui" 
        .....
    End Select
Next
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. My code was actually working although I needed to place the Termination Phase of my code last. I was performing math calculations first and doing other things last. And it slowed things down dramatically.

Comment: You are welcom! I have tonns of time on my hands and nothing to do with it :)